# How to add click event JS for interactive map of the mall?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an interactive mall map. JS code works correctly on hover. But I need to add on click as well. That is, to work the same way when hovering and clicking on the menu.

Here is the JS code:

```
//map
 var id = 0;
 $(' .scheme-about__item .menu__link').mouseover(function(e) {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(isMobile()) {
       $('.area-m-' + id).addClass('hover');
    } else {
       $('.area-' + id).addClass('hover');
    }
    console.log($('.area-' + id));
 })
 
 .mouseout(function(e) {
    if(isMobile()) {
       $('.area-m-' + id).removeClass('hover');
    } else {
       $('.area-' + id).removeClass('hover');
    }
 });


    function isMobile() {
        var res = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|Windows Phone|PlayBook|BB10|Nokia/i);
        if (res != null)
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
//map

let  id = 0;
let menuLink = document.querySelector('.scheme-about__item .menu__link');

menuLink.addEventListener('click',mapFunction);
menuLink.addEventListener('mouseover',mapFunction);
menuLink.addEventListener('mouseout',mapFunction);


function mapFunction(e){
    id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    if(isMobile()) {
        document.querySelector('.area-m-' + id).classList.add('hover');
        } else {
        document.querySelector('.area-' + id).classList.add('hover');
        }
        console.log(document.querySelector('.area-' + id)
    
}

function isMobile() {
    var res = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile|Windows Phone|PlayBook|BB10|Nokia/i);
    if (res != null)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work (

Comment: Provide here the HTML and CSS code as well. Let me check manually. Thank you

Comment: I can't' add here all code. Please review the link: https://codepen.io/Elena_1986/pen/jOZpBeq